# VBS If Then Else

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to VBS and I'm attempting to make a start on a UAC in Windows - A will to do and in turn, learn.

I don't understand why I keep getting a syntax error on the line before the last End If

If you could help, I'd be greatly appreciative!

```
CurPass = ReadIni("C:\Program Files\User Account Control\ident.ini", "pass", "pass")
InpPass = inputbox("Please enter your current password:")
If InpPass = CurPass Then
NewPass = inputbox("Please enter your new password")
    if NewPass=CurPass Then 
        KpPass=msgbox("Your new password is the same as your old password. Keep old password?",4+32,"UAC")
        if KpPass=7 Then MsgBox("Please try again")
        end if
    Else 
        RNewPass = inputbox("Please re-enter your new password")
    end if
    if RNewPass=NewPass then 
        WriteIni "C:\Program Files\User Account Control\ident.ini", "pass", "Pass", NewPass
    else msgbox("Your new passwords do not match. Try again.")
    end If
else msgbox("Incorrect password")
End if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no If .. Then for your last Else .. End If. This would be obvious immediately, if you had used proper indentation.

**Update: Above diagnosis is wrong.**

I think you want this structure:

```
CurPass = ""
InpPass = ""
If InpPass = CurPass Then
   NewPass = ""
   If NewPass = CurPass Then
      KpPass = ""
      If KpPass = "7" Then
         KpPass = "4711"
      End If
   Else
      RNewPass = ""
   End If
   If RNewPass = NewPass Then
      RNewPass = "xx"
   Else
      RNewPass = "yy"
   End If
Else
   CurPass = "whatamess"
End If
```

Then VBScript lost its way when you wrote:

```
if KpPass=7 Then MsgBox("Please try again")
end if
```

You can have 'short ifs' like

```
If Condition Then OneStatementAction
```

but then there should be no `End If`. It's a bit like omitting {} for single line/statement conditionals in other C alike languages. That is: better avoided.

Answer (score -2):

End IF is a expresion that tells to VB.NET that you done your Conditions.

Every IF may close with an END IF

so your code may be like:

```
If textbox1.text = "Cat" Then

   Do something
Else
   Do not do that thing
End If
```

Check your code again and avoid writing End IFs and then elses look:

```
If textbox1.text = "Cat" Then

   Do something
End IF

Else
   Do not do that thing
End If
```

// This will not work! You can t have more than one IF in a contition:

This is incorect:

```
IF something Then
  IF blabla bla then
Else
Endif
```

See here a link where you can learn how to use therse:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Comment: Ooops, my fail, but the rule its the same for understanding IF And ENd IF